# Ember Quickstart tutorial: Parsing error: Unexpected character '@' in '@action'

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just started using Ember and I have some trouble with the [Ember Quickstart tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/getting-started/quick-start/). Currently, I get `Parsing error: Unexpected character '@'` in line 5 of `people-list.js`:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class PeopleListComponent extends Component {
  @action
  showPerson(person) {
    alert(`The person's name is ${person}!`);
  }
}
```

What's wrong here? The code is copied from the tutorial.

This is the output of `ember -v`:

```
ember-cli: 3.18.0
node: 11.13.0
os: darwin x64
```

This is `my package.json`. I can run `npm install`, but `yarn install` gives me `The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "10.* || >= 12". Got "11.13.0"`.

```
{
  "name": "ember-quickstart",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Small description for ember-quickstart goes here",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "lint:hbs": "ember-template-lint .",
    "lint:js": "eslint .",
    "start": "ember serve",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ember/jquery": "^0.5.2",
    "@ember/optional-features": "^0.6.3",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.7.0",
    "ember-ajax": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^7.1.2",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.8.2",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.1",
    "ember-cli-template-lint": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-data": "~3.9.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
    "ember-qunit": "^3.4.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^5.0.1",
    "ember-source": "~3.9.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "^5.2.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.7.0",
    "qunit-dom": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.* || >= 12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-cli": "^3.18.0",
    "@glimmer/component": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Adding some text here as SO won't let me post the question otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You're `ember-source` is set to  `~3.9.0`. I'm pretty sure `@action` is an Octane feature that was added in 3.14.

Either update `ember-source` to 3.14 or newer or switch to the 3.9.0 documentation. I'd recommend updating as Octane is awesome.

Comment: Thanks. I updated `ember-source` (and later, also `ember-data`) to `~3.14.0`, but that didn't help. It seems all that Ember stuff I installed with `npm install -g ember-cli` a few weeks ago is outdated. Can I get a full `package.json` as it should look like somewhere?

Comment: you could do `npm install -g ember-cli@3.18` I think. Then you can run `ember new` and will get an up-to-date app.

Comment: According to your `ember -v` output, you're already using `ember-cli` version `3.18` so a new app should start with Ember 3.18.

Comment: Your issue is not that much about the `ember-source` package but about other packages and their configuration required for Ember Octane. You should [upgrade your full ember app](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/upgrading/) not only the ember-source package.

Comment: Your `package.json` also misses the `ember-cli` dependency, which is very strange. You should compare your project to [a newly generated project](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/master/package.json) for your target version.

Comment: I'd recommend using ember-cli-update to update your ember app correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The output says you currently have ember-cli 3.18, but your app seems to have been generated by an older ember-cli 3.9 as indicated by devDependencies.

As mentioned in the comments, 3.9 does not have access to some of the current features unless you install some polyfills.

If regenerating the app is a possibility, I would suggest doing it.

1. Run `ember --version` to make sure 3.18 is being called
2. Run `ember new my-app-name` and check that `package.json` has 3.18 for ember-source.
3. Go through the quickstart!

Alternatively, you can run `npx ember-cli new my-app-name` and it *should* generate an app using the latest ember-cli version available in npm.

If you don't want to lose some work you might have done, you can check out [ember-cli-update](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update) by running something like `npx ember-cli-update`. Check the README for more info.